# How to understand Bird and Hughes foldr

Tags: functional-programming, lambda

Got lost trying to understand Charles Bird's *Introduction to Functional Programming* as well as John Hughes' *Why Functional Programming Matters*. Specifically their discussion of **foldr**.

```
length = foldr count 0
count a n = n + 1
```

When this is applied to a list, say, [1, 2, 3], it should come back with 3. Here's Bird (p 66):

```
(#) = foldr oneplus 0
       where oneplus x n = 1 + n
```

And here's another more lambda treatment:

```
length = foldr (λx.λn.(1 + n)) 0
```

I'm at a loss to understand what's going on with this foldr once we start trying to apply it to a list like [1, 2, 3]. I'm just not seeing what the variables x and n refer to. A simple one like sum:

```
sum = foldr (+) 0
```

for [1, 2, 3] is

```
(+) 1 ((+) 2 ((+) 3 0)) = 6
```

using Hughes' notation of replacing the list's implied cons with the function/operator and the identity for the list's implied nil, then (prefix) adding -- I understand. But not when dealing with these mysterious variables. Maybe someone can walk me through how the list and the variables interact.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to a function passed to `foldr` are an element of the list being folded over and the accumulator (essentially, the thing being calculated).

More explicit names for these arguments might help:

```
length = foldr count 0
count ignored_elt length_so_far = length_so_far + 1
```

Another approach to understanding folds is to write them as a recursive function, and also write the fold, and inspect both definitions to see how they are similar. After a few of these you should start to understand the pattern that folds capture. (Hint: when doing this, try to avoid commutative operations like `+` as they can obscure the difference between left and right folds).

Comment: Hughes' explanation is good at stressing the recursion. Yes, I figured the n was an incrementation variable. But I thought that was an imperative trick. What I don't understand is the lambda calc aspect of the n variable. In the lambda function above x is the bound variable and n is -- what? Could someone show me how the recursion would look for the lambda function? Perhaps with an example like [1, 2, 3].

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In `λx . λn . 1 + n`, both `x` and `n` are arguments (this is the lambda calculus equivalent of a two-argument function). There's no recursion except that implied by the existence of `foldr`.

Comment: If I follow what Hughes says, I sub in the count, i.e., (1+n) for the Cons in a list. For [1,2,3] we have Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3 Nil)) becoming (n+1) 1 ((n+1) 2 ((n+1) 3 0) ... which is what? I'm still not grasping what the n is and where it came from.

Comment: @LawrenceBottorff You don't substitute `1 + n` for the cons, you substitute the function `λx . λn . 1 + n`